# eos smart contract constructor

Tags: smart-contract, constructor

when is smart contract constructor triggered for the first time? I know it is triggered every time action is pushed, but what if i want something to be triggered when smart contract is deployed for the first time? Do I need separate action for that and to keep constructor as simple as possible?

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it is triggered when they are deployed using "set contract" on cleos.

Since there are no gas fees in EOS, it might not be a bad idea to add an initiation action for safety. However, it would require you making sure that there are no security risks and you set the right authority check in-line. They did it this way for eosbetcasino

https://gitlab.com/EOSBetCasino/eosbetdice_public/blob/master/EOSBetDice.cpp